# Create new field type for custom content

Tags: drupal-7, customization, field

I want to create a new content type called "Message". It will have a couple of fields, "message-body" which will be plain text and "addressees". The addressees field should reflect a list of the registered users of the site.

The idea is to create a field type that will be a checklist where all users of the site can be selected, and those that are will receive the message in "message-body" via drupal_set_message($msg).

I am not suceeding so far in creating a custom field type. The Field API documentation is not very clear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe already found the solutions for you problem.

I think in your case you can use Entity Reference. In your custom content type you can create a new field with the Entity Reference type. Then on the configuration page you can choose which entity to reference, like node, taxonomy or users, with different types of widget.

[Here's a link of the Entity Reference module.](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a content type via the menu interface `www.yoursite.com/admin/structure/types/add`.

Or you need it as a module that you can re-distribute?

An easier way then is to make use of [features](http://drupal.org/project/features). It allows you to 'export' a built content type into a module. Enabling the module (on another site), then creates all the fields that where in the export.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure that you understand what I require. It is not creating a new content type that is the problem, but creating a custom field for that content type. I am more or less being able to manage, following this nice tutorial: http://evolvingweb.ca/story/poutine-maker-introduction-field-api-drupal-7-part-1

Comment: Then I misunderstood you indeed.